# error: 'butt_flag' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino

ошибка при компиляции программы в среде разработки Arduino IDE.

> C:\Users\717177\Desktop\ArduinoFirzt\ArduinoFirzt.ino: In function 'void loop()':
> ArduinoFirzt:12:20: error: 'butt_flag' was not declared in this scope
> if (butt == 1 && butt_flag == 0)
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\717177\Desktop\ArduinoFirzt\ArduinoFirzt.ino:12:20: note: suggested alternative: 'but_flag'
> if (butt == 1 && butt_flag == 0)
> ^~~~~~~~~
> but_flag
> ArduinoFirzt:20:20: error: 'butt_flag' was not declared in this scope
> if (butt == 0 && butt_flag == 1)
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\717177\Desktop\ArduinoFirzt\ArduinoFirzt.ino:20:20: note: suggested alternative: 'but_flag'
> if (butt == 0 && butt_flag == 1)
> ^~~~~~~~~
> but_flag
> exit status 1
> 'butt_flag' was not declared in this scope
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код:

```
boolean but_flag = 0;
boolean butt;
void setup() 
{
pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);

}
void loop() 
{
butt = !digitalRead(3);

if (butt == 1 && butt_flag == 0)
{
butt_flag = 1;
Serial.println(" Button pressed ");
}



if (butt == 0 && butt_flag == 1) 
{
butt_flag = 0;
Serial.println(" Button released ");
}




}
```

Извините, я наверное извращенец, но мне именно так нравится ставить скобки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас объявлена переменная but_flag, а вы используете but**t**_flag